# Error in SharePoint Duration Calculation Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have three columns - a start date/time, an end date/time, and a duration. I found a guide for setting up the duration column to calculate plain text based on the time/date columns, but something in the syntax appears to glitch on a few of the items that last precisely one hour.

Can anyone help me spot the error here? This is the formula I'm using.

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>0,CONCATENATE(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)," ",IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>1,"hours","hour")),""),IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>0,CONCATENATE(" ",MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])," ",IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>1,"minutes","minute")),""))
```

Same formula, more readable.

```
=CONCATENATE(
    IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>0,
        CONCATENATE(
            INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24),
            " ",
            IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>1,
                "hours",
                "hour"
            )
        ),
        ""
    ),
    IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>0,
        CONCATENATE(
            " ",
            MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time]),
            " ",
            IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>1,
                "minutes",
                "minute"
            )
        ),
        ""
    )
)
```

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of missing durations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way time differences are handled, you need to add the case when the duration is 1 hour.

Here is your corrected code:

```
=CONCATENATE(
    IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>0,
        CONCATENATE(
            INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24),
            " ",
            IF(INT(([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])*24)>1,
                "hours",
                "hour"
            )
        ),
        ""
    ),
    IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])>=0,
        CONCATENATE(
            " ",
            MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time]),
            " ",
            IF(MINUTE([End Date and Time]-[Start date and time])<>1,
                "minutes",
                "minute"
            )
        ),
        ""
    )
)
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much. I was puzzling over that for quite a while.